# Subscriber not called in symfony 5.3

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I'm starting to learn the symfony event system and to test it I created a "subscriber" that listens to the **AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE** event and dumps it.

I then tried to connect with fake data, but nothing happens.

I then tried to listen to another event **KernelEvents::REQUEST** and it works, so I don't see where the problem can come from.

MY SUBSCRIBER :

````
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LoginFailureEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LoginSuccessEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;




class AuthenticationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'securityauthenticationsuccess',
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE => 'securityauthenticationfailure',
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'KernelRequest',
            
            
        ];
        
    }

    public function securityauthenticationfailure(LoginFailureEvent $event){
          dump($event);
    }

    public function securityauthenticationsuccess(LoginSuccessEvent $event){
        dump($event);
  }

  public function KernelRequest(RequestEvent $event){
    dump($event);
}
  

}```


MY SERVICE.YAML :

```# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:

    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
````

[image: Listener not Called]

[image: listener not called 2]

Comment: Does your authentication success handler get called?  Please confirm you have `enable_authenticator_manager: true` in your security.yaml file.  You can use `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher LoginFailureEvent` to confirm your wiring.

Comment: You might also try using dd (dump and die) instead of just dump.  It's possible the dump info is being lost in the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The Core\AuthenticationEvents class is part of the older authentication system.  For the new HTTP based system, the event class name is used for the event name.  So:

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            LoginSuccessEvent::class => 'onLoginSuccess',
            LoginFailureEvent::class => 'onLoginFailure',
        ];
    }
```

Should get you one step further.

It might also be instructive to look at some of the listener classes under `vendor\symfony\security-http\Authenticator\EventListener`

By the way, I tested this code using an make:auth generated authenticator that extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator.  All out of the box stuff.  Works as expected.